# Delphi Console XE7 Clearscreen

Tags: delphi, console, screen

How I can clear the console screen in a delphi console application (delphi xe6 or higher) I have searched the internet and the help file but cannot seem to find it?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/99261

Comment: This is related to a delphi console application not a c++ or microsoft application, i am trying to find out if there is a function allready provided in the delphi units to provide this functionality!

Comment: You must have different Internet from me. I found [`this`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21701) as the first link (have not tried, nor reviewed that code though).

Comment: TLama, like i said I am looking for the delphi code not the c++ function, but if it allready exist in the delphi units or libraries.

Comment: It's worth pointing out to you that Delphi on Windows is built on top of the platform. The Delphi runtime library provides many facilities, but is by no means comprehensive. There are times when you need to program against the platform beneath the Delphi runtime. This is one of those times. Knowing that platform, and how to understand C++ example code is essential for such tasks.

Comment: @TLama Unfortunately that Delphi example code is quite dire!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am trying to find out if there is a function already provided in the delphi units to provide this functionality.

There is no such function provided by the Delphi runtime library. You will need to write your own function using the operating system services. This article on MSDN explains how to do it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/99261

Translate that like so:

```
procedure ClearScreen;
var
  stdout: THandle;
  csbi: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
  ConsoleSize: DWORD;
  NumWritten: DWORD;
  Origin: TCoord;
begin
  stdout := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  Win32Check(stdout<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  Win32Check(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout, csbi));
  ConsoleSize := csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
  Origin.X := 0;
  Origin.Y := 0;
  Win32Check(FillConsoleOutputCharacter(stdout, ' ', ConsoleSize, Origin, 
    NumWritten));
  Win32Check(FillConsoleOutputAttribute(stdout, csbi.wAttributes, ConsoleSize, Origin, 
    NumWritten));
  Win32Check(SetConsoleCursorPosition(stdout, Origin));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, the link on Embarcadero I tried allready and SetConsoleTextAttribute and some of the functions in the solution are not found in the default delphi console application for XE6 or 7, I have found it does to work in those version, possible I am missing a unit declaration or something.

Comment: "not to work" is not a valid problem description. I cannot help with that unless you provide details. You asked if there were functions in the RTL. That was your question. You clarified explicitly in the comments. Is that not the case. In other words, you made it clear that you wanted to know if there were RTL functions for this, and the answer is equally clear.

Comment: The code in the EDN article requires you to use the Windows unit.

Comment: Ok then I will have to code the function using the operating system services, thanks David!

Comment: Ok added the windows unit that lets the function compile but it does not work, I get lot sof extra garbage characters on the screen, will try and if I can fix it!

Comment: That Delphi code is just useless. Yet another good reason to learn C++ enough to understand code examples. An awful lot of dire Delphi code can be found on the web. The MSDN code is where to start. I've translated it for you.

Comment: Thanks David, Used the function you provided and that works, took me a while to answer, as I was at lunch!